# how to make a function "call" accepting any function as an argument and arguments for her in python?

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

how to make a function "call" accepting any function as an argument and arguments for her in python?

For example,

```
def add(a, b):
  return a + b
call(add, 2, 3) == 5
call(add, a = 4, b = 1) == 5
call(max, [3,2,4,7]) == 7
```

I tried this:

```
def call(fun, *args, **kwargs):
    if args and kwargs:
        return fun(args, kwargs)
    elif kwargs:
        return fun(kwargs)
    elif args:
        return fun(args)
    else:
        return None
```

That's what I got:

```
Failed. Runtime error

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 22, in <module>
    got = call(my_sum, 1, 2, 7)
  File "jailed_code", line 9, in call
    return fun(args)
  File "jailed_code", line 19, in my_sum
    return sum(args)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you mean: `def call(fun, *args, **kwargs): return fun(*args,**kwargs)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpack `args` and `kwargs` inside `call`:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def call(fun, *args, **kwargs):
    if args and kwargs:
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    elif kwargs:
        return fun(**kwargs)
    elif args:
        return fun(*args)
    else:
        return None

print(call(add, 2, 3)) # 5
print(call(add, a = 4, b = 1)) # 5
print(call(max, [3,2,4,7])) # 7
```